# sed with multiple expression for in-place argument

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing, sed

I am trying to replace multiple words in a file by using

```
sed -i #expression1 #expression2
```

### file

```
Something  123 item1
Something  456 item2
Something  768 item3
Something  353 item4
```

### Output (Desired)

```
anything  123 stuff1
anything  456 stuff2
anything  768 stuff3
anything  353 stuff4
```

### Try-outs

I can get the following output by using `sed -i` two times.

```
 sed -i 's/Some/any/g' file
 sed -i 's/item/stuff/g' file
```

Can I have any possible way of making this as a single in-place command like

```
sed -i 's/Some/any/g' -i 's/item/stuff/g' file
```

When I tried the above code it takes `s/item/stuff/g` as a file and tries working on it.

Comment: If your files are similar to the example above (i.e they follow the same pattern) you can do it with a single substitution: `sed - i 's/Some\(.*\)item/any\1stuff/' file`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Depending on the version of `sed` on your system you may be able to do

```
sed -i 's/Some/any/; s/item/stuff/' file
```

You don't need the `g` after the final slash in the `s` command here, since you're only doing one replacement per line.

Alternatively:

```
sed -i -e 's/Some/any/' -e 's/item/stuff/' file
```

Or:

```
sed -i '
  s/Some/any/
  s/item/stuff/' file
```

The `-i` option (a GNU extension now supported by a few other implementations though some need `-i ''` instead) tells `sed` to edit files in place; if there are characters immediately after the `-i` then `sed` makes a backup of the original file and uses those characters as the backup file's extension. Eg,

```
sed -i.bak 's/Some/any/; s/item/stuff/' file
```

or

```
sed -i'.bak' 's/Some/any/; s/item/stuff/' file
```

will modify `file`, saving the original to `file.bak`.

Of course, on a Unix (or Unix-like) system, we normally use '~' rather than '.bak', so

```
sed -i~ 's/Some/any/;s/item/stuff/' file
```

Comment: Note that you're describing the GNU variant. The BSD variant (as in FreeBSD or OS/X) _requires_ an argument for `-i`. So `sed -i '' 's/a/b/;s/c/d/' file` or `sed -i .back 's/a/b/;s/c/d/'` or `sed -i.back 's/a/b/;s/c/d/'` there. Other `sed` implementations generally don't support `-i`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas for clarifying that. And I guess I should have been more explicit in saying that in GNU sed there **cannot** be a space between the `-i` and the extension.

Comment: `sed -i 's/$username = "root"/$username = "newuser"/; s/$password = "password"/$password = "passwd"/; s/$dbname="handicraftstore"/$dbname="handicraft"' Web/database.php` results  `sed: -e expression #1, char 141: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: @alhelal Sorry, comments are not the proper place to ask questions. But anyway, your last `s` command is missing its final `/`.

Comment: @PM2Ring as I didn't notice that I guessed it is related your solution. However, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can chain sed expressions together with ";"

```
%sed -i 's/Some/any/g;s/item/stuff/g' file1
%cat file1
anything  123 stuff1
anything  456 stuff2
anything  768 stuff3
anything  353 stuff4
```

Answer (score 6):

Multiple expression using multiple `-e` options:

```
sed -i.bk -e 's/Some/any/g' -e 's/item/stuff/g' file
```

or you can use just one:

```
sed -i.bk -e 's/Some/any/g;s/item/stuff/g' file
```

You should give an extension for backup file, since when some implementation of `sed`, like [OSX sed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) does not work with empty extension (You must use `sed -i ''` to override the original files).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/Some/any/|%s/item/stuff/|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close